# File that is only readable with root privileges

Tags: bash, sudo, executable, chmod, rc

I have a binary file that needs to run at startup on all accounts (including unprivileged user accounts), so a command to run it will be put into `/etc/rc.local`. The program itself will have only execute permissions so that it cannot be read or modified by an unprivileged user. It is located in `/usr/bin`.

However, it needs to access a secret key when it runs (key is in `/usr/share`). Is it possible to create a file containing the secret key that will not be readable or writable to all common users, but readable by the program? Could the file take advantage of the program being privileged?

Perhaps it could have some sort of setup with the file permissions (chmod)? Or is there a way that that it should be encrypted in some way?

Comment: Just checking: You will be using `sudo` or `su` in `rc.local` to run this command?

Comment: I believe `sudo`, because the program just needs to download a file into a system directory.

Comment: @muru Do I need su or sudo in `rc.local` at all?

Comment: That's what I want to verify. If you want that program to run **as** an unprivileged user, you'll have to use sudo or su. Commands in rc.local run as root.

Comment: It's in `rc.local`, so it should be just fine. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it, as you say, "needs to run at startup on an unpriveleged user account", then it will necessarily have access to all files that the unpriveleged user account in question has access to.

You could create a dedicated unpriveleged user account for the purpose of running the script. Set the permissions on the secret key file so that only that dedicated user account can read it. But it sounds like you need to run the program under a specific pre-existing user account so that might not work for you.

There are other solutions, such as running it in a `chroot()` that has access to the secret key, but whether or not that's viable depends on that it does and what else, exactly, besides the secret key file, it needs access to.

You will not need to use `sudo` in any case because `/etc/rc.local` runs as root so you can `su` directly to whichever account you ultimately choose to run the program under.

**EDIT** after clarification of question:

> It needs to execute every time a user of any sort logs in.

I see. This is quite different from running it once only at startup using `/etc/rc.local` as you originally stated!

Your best bet in this case will probably be to try to embed the secret key in the binary instead of accessing it as an external file, have the binary owned by root and executable but not readable by other users (permissions such as `rwx--x--x`. The users will not be able to get access to the key (unless they compromise root on the system) but they can run the binary.

If you cannot embed the secret key in the binary then you can make the binary setuid to some user that can access the secret key... but take all the care that goes with writing setuid binaries.

Comment: *If it, as you say, "needs to run at startup on an unprivileged user account", then it will necessarily have access to all files that the unprivileged user account in question has access to.* Gotcha. I forgot to mention that the binary file is in `usr/bin`. So all it really needs to do is access the secret key file, which should be in `usr/share`. It needs to execute every time a user of any sort logs in. Really, I'm just concerned about the user getting into the binary file and the key file. If they are protected with permissions, it should be no issue, correct? Thanks.

Comment: I also edited the question to explain those changes. Hopefully it should make more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this and sticking with me. Sorry for the confusion :)